# Does Google hand over captcha IPs to webmasters?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, google

Google gets to know a user's IP when someone enters a captcha even if they are using tor (see http://www.wired.com/2014/12/google-one-click-recaptcha/). So, If I go to a non-google website, such as cnn.com, and it asks me for a captcha for submitting a particular form, will it hand over my IP to cnn?

Comment: "Google gets to know a user's IP" [Citation needed]. Nothing in the article you linked indicates that google learns anything except the exit node's IP, which the webmaster can see without involving google.

Answer (score 2):

CodesInChaos is correct.

When you visit a website they can view the IP address you connect from. That is how Google views your IP address, as for the captcha your browser connects to Google's servers. **When you connect to a site they can see your IP address, regardless if you enter a captcha or not.**

Answer (score 1):

As per [@CodesInChaos comment](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6313/does-google-hand-over-captcha-ips-to-webmasters#comment6241_6313):

> Google gets to know a user's IP.<sup>Citation needed</sup>

Nothing in the article you linked indicates that Google learns anything except the exit node's IP, which the webmaster can see without involving google.